# How to use IIS URL rewrite for ColdFusion to remove Server header and other varibles from Header Response? For IIS (8 and above versions)

Tags: security, coldfusion, iis-8, coldfusion-2016

As a part of security configuration, we should not be revealing the "Server" variable and other variables in the Header Response. How can I remove these variables for a ColdFusion server hosted on IIS?

Answer (score 6):

1. Download and Install "URL rewrite" from https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
2. Go to the configured Jakarta folder and add a `web.config` here. To add a URL rewrite outbound rule to the "Jakarta" virtual directory, we need a `web.config`. The `web.config` should have an outbound rule and the variable removal rules mentioned below.
3. Add an outbound rule to `web.config`, for erasing the server header response value and set it to blank.

   ```
   <system.webServer>
       <outboundRules>
         <rule name="Remove Server">
           <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern=".*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" />
         </rule>
       </outboundRules>
     </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
   ```
4. For server tag value removal for all static files like .css/.js files, add this to `web.config`:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   </configuration>`
   ```
5. Add the code below to `web.config` for removal of `X-Powered-By` and `X-AspNet-Version`

   ```
   <configuration>
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
       <remove name="Server" />
       <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
     </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
   </configuration>
   ```
6. Convert PortalTools from virtual directory to Application and add the same `web.config` to the PortalTools folder as well.

Comment: Just a note that if you edit this setting via the IIS Manager, it just creates / updates the related ``web.config`. Try and keep this file in source control since it will be in the root of the site anyway.